# Update SQL Server table with interdependant functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have the following update statement in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET COLUMN1 = FN_GETFIRSTVALUE(T.VALUE1),
    COLUMN2 = FN_GETSECONDVALUE(T.VALUE1, T.COLUMN1)
FROM MY_TABLE AS T
INNER JOIN ...
```

So `FN_GETSECONDVALUE` accepts an input parameter which is returned from `FN_GETFIRSTVALUE`.  I thought about using a [table function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167399/Using-Table-Valued-Functions-in-SQL-Server)... but I can't see how I could update two columns with this.  Is there another / better way to do this?  I don't want to call the function twice, or split it into a select / update.

Comment: Each assignment in the `SET` clause on an `UPDATE` is (effectively) applied in parallel. `COLUMN2` can depend on `COLUMN1`, but it will only ever be the *old* value of `COLUMN1` (from before the `UPDATE` started running). One party trick is to swap the value of two columns: `UPDATE tab SET A=B,B=A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest change to your example would be as follows...

```
UPDATE
  MY_TABLE
SET
  COLUMN1 = FN_GETFIRSTVALUE(T.VALUE1),
  COLUMN2 = FN_GETSECONDVALUE(T.VALUE1, FN_GETFIRSTVALUE(T.VALUE1))
FROM
  MY_TABLE AS T
INNER JOIN
  ...
```

SQL server is good at re-using results and so the first function does not necessarily get executed twice.  It is, however, still a bit messy to even write the call to the function twice.

Instead you can write the re-use yourself using `APPLY`...

```
UPDATE
  MY_TABLE
SET
  COLUMN1 = first_result.val,
  COLUMN2 = second_result.val
FROM
  MY_TABLE AS T
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT dbo.FN_GETFIRSTVALUE(T.VALUE1) AS val)          AS first_result
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT dbo.FN_GETSEOCNDVALUE(first_result.val) AS val) AS second_result
INNER JOIN
  ...
```

Even better, you can re-write your function as a Table Valued Function.  Even if it only returns one field in one record...

```
UPDATE
  MY_TABLE
SET
  COLUMN1 = first_result.val,
  COLUMN2 = second_result.val
FROM
  MY_TABLE AS T
OUTER APPLY
  dbo.FN_GETFIRSTVALUE(T.VALUE1)           AS first_result
OUTER APPLY
  dbo.FN_GETSEOCNDVALUE(first_result.val)  AS second_result
INNER JOIN
  ...
```

In both cases this performs *much* better if the Table Valued functions as defined as Inline-Functions *(just a single query)* than if the are defined as Multi-Statement-Functions *(including internal variables, IF statements, etc)*.

Finally, depending on your needs you can even wrap both functions into one...

```
UPDATE
  MY_TABLE
SET
  COLUMN1 = result.val1
  COLUMN2 = result.val2
FROM
  MY_TABLE AS T
OUTER APPLY
  dbo.FN_GETBOTHVALUES(T.VALUE1)           AS result
INNER JOIN
  ...
```

*(Where the function returns one record with 2 fields, named `val1` and `val2`.)*

So, all in all, you have a whole host of options here.  And that's just using `APPLY`, there are other option with Common Table Expressions...

```
WITH
  step1 AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    dbo.FUNCTION1(T.column1) AS result1
  FROM
    MY_TABLE AS T
  INNER JOIN
    ...
)
,
  step2 AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    dbo.FUNCTION2(T.result1) AS result2
  FROM
    step1
)

UPDATE
  step2
SET
  column1 = result1,
  column2 = result2
```

So many options...